# how to dynamically create models and routes in node js based on user created schemas developed through an angular front-end

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

I am a MEAN newbie working on an MEAN stack app that will let users interactively define their own mongoose schemas and then populate them with data (e.g. for a shopping list or a list of contacts or anything else). I have succeeded in (1) enabling the user to create a set of fields using a form in angular that can be turned into schemas; and (2) posting the json for the new schema to the node server.

I then plan to turn this json into a schema. I'm thinking it would make most sense to use [mongoose-gen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-gen) (and that looks pretty straightforward to me insofar as making a schema is concerned)...

The code so far looks like this...

Angular:

```
$scope.makeJson = function() {
    $http.get('http://localhost:3000/sets/' + $scope.set._id)
        .success(function (data, status) {

         objectname = data.title;
         this[objectname] = data;

         $http.post('/makeschema',this[objectname]).
            success(function() {
                console.log("Success");
            })
            .error(function(data){
             console.log('Error: ' + data);
         });  

    }).error(function (data, status) {
            $scope.response = 'Request failed';
    });  
  }
```

Node:

```
app.post('/makeschema', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    // this is where I intend to use mongoose-gen to create a schema (see below)
});
```

But what then (i.e. once I have created the schema)? How would I get from here to actually having routes set up that link back in to my angular front-end? All my pre-defined schemas have a `schemaName.js` file in the `/models` folder and a `schemaNames.js` in the `/routes` folder and are hooked up with the usual thing in `app.js`:

```
var sets = require('./routes/sets')
app.use('/sets', sets);
```

So how could I proceed to actually get the newly created models accessible in angular? Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Is having them create their own schema an important requirement? Normally for something like this you'd just add the data into an existing model. You can even go full schema-less with `{strict:false}` to let them add whatever.

Comment: I'm not sure! Can you point me to any examples of how that might work? I want users to be able to manage different types of lists and potentially (eventually) even link those lists together (e.g. add someone from a person list to a project list, etc.)... and also filter, cluster, sort, etc. the items in lists... I thought I would need schemas to make that possible, but realise I may be wrong! And by list I mean something like a mongodb document with N-number of properties... Thank you!

Comment: For linking documents you can have [referenced documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). You could also have Arrays of Mixed type Objects. With advanced mongoose queries you could filter, sort (cluster?) those arrays. There's lots of options. It's hard to recommend without fully knowing your use-case. But I just wanna make sure you're fully aware of all standard ways before deciding to go on with non-standard ways. A schema IMO should be defined by you (as a programmer), and not have clients just willy nilly create them. It raises all sorts of security flags!

Comment: I am familiar with using mongoose's populate to link documents. I want to allow users to define a set of properties for their lists (just like a schema) and to use that definition to automatically create forms that allow users to populate their lists (just like documents). Then they could perform whatever regular db operations they might want (e.g. filtering, sorting, updating, linking, etc.). If there is anything more specific I could tell you that might help you answer, please let me know. Many thanks!

Comment: @laggingreflex so I've had a play around and I've decided to just have two actual schemas, one with which allows a user to define the structure of a virtual schema and another which stores all items regardless of the 'schema' and is cross-referenced by type. So far, so good. I will have to see if I get stuck further down the line when I start doing more complex cross-references... Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.